# Rename variable on inheritance

Tags: c#

I'm just wondering if it is possible..

I have a base class, with a variable called Level. I then derive a class from it, but here Level should be called Points.

Is there any way to rename the Level variable in the derived class?

**Edit** - Excuse me for calling a property a variable. I'm quite new to programming, and especially to classes (Which our teacher doesn't teach us for some reason)

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Because the classes are the same in essence, but one has levels and the other has points (it's for a game by the way)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest you could get with inheritance would be:

```
class BaseClass
{
  protected int Level { get; set; }
}

class SubClass : BaseClass
{
  public int Points { get { return Level; } set { Level = value; } }
}
```

But that doesn't actually *expose* BaseClass.Level, since a protected property is only visible to subclasses.

As @Jason explains, a subclass can't obscure the public interface of its base class. If you really wanted to do that, you could *encapsulate* the base in a new object that exposes its properties:

```
class A
{
   public Foo { get; set; }
   public Bar { get; set; }
   public Level { get; set;}
}

class B
{
  private A _internalA;

  public Foo { get { return _internalA.Foo; }  set { _internalA.Foo = value; } }
  public Bar { get { return _internalA.Bar; }  set { _internalA.Bar= value; } }
  public Points { get { return _internalA.Level; }  set { _internalA.Level = value; } }
}
```

This is typically referred to as *composition*: B is composed of A, rather than inheriting from it.

Comment: Technically, that's not renaming Level. It just exposes it via a new public property.

Comment: Thanks! (So that's what get and set can be used for..)

Comment: The second option is actually better for what I want, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark it as accepted (click the checkmark below the voting buttons) if that's what you're going with. Cheers.

Comment: Was waiting for the 15 minutes to expire ;)

Answer (score 3):

Classes do not contain variables; they contain fields and properties (and methods, indexers, etc.)

I assume you're referring to properties, because fields shouldn't be public anyway.

There is no way to change the name of a property inherited from a base class.

What you can do:

**Option 1**

Add a property `Points` in addition to the property `Level` inherited from the base class:

```
class MyBaseClass
{
    public int Level { get; set; }
}

class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public int Points
    {
        get { return this.Level; }
        set { this.Level = value; }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
MyDerivedClass x = new MyDerivedClass();
x.Points = 42;
Console.WriteLine(x.Level); // prints "42"
```

**Option 2**

Turn your base class into an interface, so you can implement it [explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), thereby hiding the property `Level`:

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    int Level { get; set; }
}

class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    int IMyInterface.Level
    {
        get { return this.Points; }
        set { this.Points = value; }
    }

    public int Points { get; set; }
}
```

Example:

```
MyClass y = new MyClass();
y.Points = 42; // works
y.Level = 99; // doesn't work

IMyInterface z = y;
z.Level = 99; // works
Console.WriteLine(y.Points); // prints "99"
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to rename the Level variable in the derived class?

No, stop and think about why for a second. If you have an instance of `Base`, you could refer to the property `Level`. Now if you have an instance of `Derived`, it is also a `Base`, and therefore it should have property named `Level`. It's that simple: a `Derived` is also a `Base` so whatever you can do with `Base` you should be able to do with `Derived`.

But, you could do this:

```
class Base {
    protected int Level { get; set; }
}

class Derived : Base {
    public int Points { get { return this.Level; } set { this.Level = value; } }
}
```

Note that `Level` is no longer publicly visible.

Comment: There must be cases where your first paragraph isn't valid. Otherwise, why would C# support the [new keyword](The new keyword for properties would get you int) for member definitions? :-)

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible. You can override the behavior using virtual properties, but not rename it.

Answer (score 0):

As someone coming to this question in over a decade, I want to see if I can answer the original form I think it was in, which is; "Can you rename an inherited property in VB.Net?", and the answer I've found is **yes**.

Let's say you have class A:

```
Public Class A
    Public Property OriginalProperty
        Get
            ' Special Get implmenetation
        End Get
        Set (value As Object)
            ' Special Set implementation
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

And class B:

```
Public Class B
    Inherits A

    Public Property NewProperty
        Get
            Return OriginalProperty
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            MyBase.OriginalProperty = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

This retains the original get and set logic while allowing the calling code to use the new Property name. It may be worth asking why you have to refer to the same property by a different name in code, instead of just referring to the original property.